# Ajax loads the data, prints the whole table altogether, none of the DataTables features are working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've set up DataTables successfully. But now I want the data to be loaded with Ajax(serverside processing). The problem is, whenever the page loads, all the data of the whole table is being shown and none of the DataTables functionalities work anymore. I'm using NodeJS, express in my backend.

This is how the table looks like now:

[image: image 1]

My express backend:

```
adminModel.product(function(product) {
                        if (product) {
                            let dtProducts={};
                          dtProducts.data=product; 
                           res.send(dtProducts);
                            } else {
                    res.status(401).json({
                        data: undefined,
                        success: false
                    });
                }
            });
```

JSON data format:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 'HJNGANpf7',
    sId: '2',
    sName: 'Jaber Al Rafian',
    productsDate: '0000-00-00',
    productsTime: '12:00:00 AM',
    brand: 'gucci',
    item: 'handbag',
    color: '',
    size: '-S,-M,-L',
    style: '',
    location: '',
   quantity: '',
    packingList: '',
    fobPrice: 0,
    status: 'varified',
    featured: 0 },
  .....so on
 ]
```

HTML part:

```
    <table class="table table-hover  table-bordered table-dark table-responsive table-sm" id="table">
                <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Time</th>
                      <th scope="col">Seller Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">Brand</th>
                      <th scope="col">Item</th>
                      <th scope="col">Color</th>
                      <th scope="col">Location</th>
                      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                      <th scope="col">FOB price</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

jQuery part (DataTables initialization)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table').DataTable({
                    rowReorder: {
                    selector: 'td:nth-child(0)'
                        },
                responsive: true,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                Filter: true,
                stateSave: true,
                ordering:false,
                type:"POST",
                "ajax":{
                    "url": "/admin/test/ajax/products",
                    "type": "POST" 
                },
    columns: [
        { data : "productsDate", name: 'productsDate' },
        { data : "productsTime",name : "productsTime"},
        { data : "sName" , name : "sName" },
        { data : "brand",name : "brand" },
        { data : "item",name : "item"},
        { data : "color", name : "color" },
        { data : "location", name : "location"},
        { data : "quantity",name : "quantity" },
        { data : "fobPrice",name : "fobPrice" }
   ]
});
});
```